# How to make pdfMake to work dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdfmake

[Click here for the code](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B30hzeNSufa5SUFEVFdlRVFUdlU)

Is there any other way to print cars[Array] names if we have hundreds?

Comment: Please add the relevant code directly to your question

Comment: you have way to add code in your question in SO, why not use it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate automatically your "body" array in "docDefinition", you just need to concact your colums array value and your cars.

First, create your colums tab:

```
        var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Audi", "Bentley", "Mercedes"];
        var colums =  ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3']; // Create your colums tab
```

After that, just concat your tabs into "docDefinition" :

```
                table: {
                    body: [
                       colums.concat(cars)  // Concat your colums and cars tabs                                     
                    ]
                }
```

Comment: Th-isn't what I want. It is showing the car names continuously. What I want is, for every three names it should print the values in the next row.